# Correct use of "% Time in GC" performance counter

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I am trying to get the "% Time in GC" performance counter in ".NET CLR Memory" category programmatically.

According to the description in PerfMon,

> % Time in GC is the percentage of elapsed time that was spent in
>   performing a garbage collection (GC) since the last GC cycle. This
>   counter is usually an indicator of the work done by the Garbage
>   Collector on behalf of the application to collect and compact memory.
>   This counter is updated only at the end of every GC and the counter
>   value reflects the last observed value; its not an average.

So based on that description, my understanding is that I will have to get the performance counter periodically and calculate the average value myself.

The way I get the performance counter is

```
     string category = ".NET CLR Memory";
     string counter  = "% Time in GC";
     string instance = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
     PerformanceCounter gcPerf;

     // make sure the performance counter is available to query
     if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(category) &&
         PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counter, category) &&
         PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instance, category))
     {
        gcPerf = new PerformanceCounter(category, counter, instance);
     }
```

However, when I look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb29hack(v=vs.90).aspx, my understanding is that gcPerf.NextValue() will do the sampling and calculate the average for you.

So what exactly is the correct use of "% Time in GC"? Is calling gcPerf.NextValue() returning the average value since the method was called last time?

Comment: @HansPassant can you elaborate on it? By yes, you mean NextValue() does return the avg value? If it applies to % Time in GC, i guess it applies to all other performance counters as well?

Comment: It is like a stopwatch, you have to press it once to get started and press it again to get a measurement.  Not all perf counters work that way, just the ones that give a measurement over elapsed time.

Comment: To help with calibrating your program, try viewing the value in Process Explorer.